# Can PHPExcel add a sheet chart (as opposed to embedded chart)?

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel

At the moment of this writing the current version of [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is version 1.8.0. I know how to make a chart and embed it in a worksheet, I basically followed the [provided example](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Tests/33chartcreate.php).

[Excel allows to](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/chart-sheet.html) either embed a chart into a worksheet or otherwise make a chart sheet. A chart sheet has it's own 'tab' in Excel and Excel keeps the chart scaled to the available size in the window.

Now what I would like to know is: how to add a chart sheet with PHPExcel? Is this possible with PHPExcel 1.8.0 using the 'Excel2007' writer?

Comment: No. What's wrong with creating a new worksheet and putting a chart on it? That's basically all that Excel really does

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Mark. If you say it is not possible, at least I know for sure it is not possible :-). In response to your question: Excel keeps a chart on a chart sheet scaled to the available size in the window. I can put a chart on a worksheet, but then I would have to guess the monitor size for the screen that opens it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @MarkBaker in the comments, the answer is simply "No" (at least not in version 1.8.1).

In my use case I was using PHP to generate an Excel workbook based on some processed data from different sources. What I did is to add VBA in `Sub Workbook_Open()` on the generated workbook to move the chart from a worksheet to it's own chart sheet. Then I used `PHPExcel->getMacrosCode()` to export the binary string of macro code to some file.

Now when generating files I add that binary string with `PHPExcel->getMacrosCode(String)` and save it as `.xlsm` instead of `.xlsx`. It is a bit of a hassle, but this is how I work around this problem for me.

Note that depending on your use case you might also need to generate a certificate to sign the code, to allow your user to always trust macros.